# What's the recommended way to check if the file doesn't exists or is empty with file_get_contents() [PHP]?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm using `file_get_contents()` along with `file_put_contents()` to download some files.

I'm using as everyone suggests:

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/image.jpg');
if ($file === false) { // do stuff on failure }
```

It works flawlessly but the thing is that today I just realized that some files have been deleted or something but still the response code is 200 so `file_get_contents()` returns empty string which means `"" === false // is false` so it won't execute that code in that `if` condition.

My question is how to properly write that `if` condition to also check for an empty file?

My suggestions are:

```
if ($file == false) { // do stuff on failure or empty }

if ($file === false || strlen($file) === 0) { // do stuff on failure or empty }

if ($file === false || empty($file) { // do stuff on failure or empty }
```

PS For now I am only interested in suggestions for `file_get_contents()`

Comment: If it returns an empty string if the file doesn't exist, then it should be enough to do what you wrote, check if it's falsy: `if (!$file)` or `if ($file == false)`. You already seem to know this so I'm not really sure what your question is? _Side note:_ Checking both false and empty isn't necessary since false also is regarded as empty.

Comment: Yes, you are right `empty()` is not needed, if I use double equals but I asked for suggestions because of potential false positives. My third example was with triple equals, that's why I put `empty()` but probably my first example is enough or yours with `if(!$file)`. Edit: yes i see, thank you :)

Comment: _"Yes, you are right empty() is not needed, if I use double equals"_ - True, but my point was that the `$file === false` is not needed if you use `empty()` since `empty()` will return true if the value literally is `false` as well.

Comment: Yes sure I understand. I can use only `if( empty($file) )` because this becomes true both with empty string or false